# How can I specify on delete no action in .NET Standard 2.0 mapping? PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I want to define on delete no action in my .NET Standard 2.0 mapping, but I don't find how can I do it.

This is an example of my mappings:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<task>()
                .HasOne<job>(x => x.job).WithMany();
}
```

I'm tried using `OnDelete` method, but it just has options `Restrict`, `SetNULL`, `Cascade` and `ClientSetNULL`. If I don't specify `OnDelete` method, by default it is set to `Restrict`.

How can I specify no action in my mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table mapping independent database on entity framework. You will be use the example;

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
        .HasOptional<Standard>(s => s.Standard)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

referans: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

Comment: I'm using .NET Standard 2.0. Sorry, It's my fault. I'm going to edit the post

Comment: I using .Net core 2.2 and found EF6 document (https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#enabling-cascade-delete) 
similar use.

Comment: And are you using WillCascadeOnDelete() method? Because I don't have this method available.

Comment: Now, I tryed with new project, used EF6.2.0 from nuget. And yes, there are WillCascadeOnDelete in CascadableNavigationPropertyConfiguration class.